# R - How do you change the limit on the number of open files?

Tags: r

I'm using the quantmod package and was loading a weeks worth of data for each stock symbol.  There were approximately 6400 symbols retrieved by the stockSymbols() function but when it reached around 5003 I got

```
Error in file(fname, "w"): cannot open the connection
cannot open file 'path to temp file': Too many open files
```

Is there a work around or a setting that can change the limit on the number of open files that R permits?

Comment: I found a solution on Superuser: [changing max number of open files][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/302754/increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-file-descriptors-in-snow-leopard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a shell / OS limit which is handed down from the OS to R.
If you are on Linux, see `man bash` and look for `ulimit`: [...]

*Edit:* And credit to Josh for reminding of another limit in R's connection code.  A simple test script like this

```
N <- 130
fvec <- vector(length=N, mode="list")
for (i in 1:N) {
    fname <- paste0("/tmp/foo", i, ".tmp")
    fvec[[i]] <- file(fname, "w")
}

Sys.sleep(3)
for (i in 1:N) {
    close(fvec[[i]])
}
```

seems to die when `N > 128` but makes it fine up to somewhere near that value.  Right now, `N=125` worked for me, higher values die.

In a nutshell, you need to organize your program so that it can operate with fewer concurrently open file handles. Else, you may need to rebuild R with a higher default for open connections and make sure your OS lets you have as many too.

Comment: I thought the number of R connections was hard-coded in the R source to be 128 or so...

Comment: The error message text suggest an error report from R's Connections layer but being "caused" by the system complaining.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm running on MacOS X

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll look into refactoring my code.